# Calling WCF usng Jquery-ajax

Tags: jquery, wcf

I had gone through many posts but dint get any help. I am trying to call my WCf using jquery ajax but I always get following errors.

1. 400 (Bad Request)
2. Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My code is as below:

Web.config[Service]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="UserDetails1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>


      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <!--<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="UserDetailsBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>-->

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsbind">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                           algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="UserDetails1Behavior" name="UserDetails1.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="UserDetails1.IService1"
                   />
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
      </service>
    </services>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

IService1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace UserDetails1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract(Name = "UserDetails1.Service1")]
    public interface IService1
    {

        // TODO: Add your service operations here

        [OperationContract]
        //   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        //ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetDataUsingDataContract?composite={composite}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        string InsertUserDetail(UserDetails userInfo);

        [OperationContract]
        //   [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        //ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        DataSet SelectUserDetails();

        [OperationContract]
        //   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        //ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        bool DeleteUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo);

        [OperationContract]
        //   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        //ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        DataSet UpdateUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo);

        [OperationContract]
        //   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        //ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetDataUsingDataContract?composite={composite}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        void UpdateRegistrationTable(UserDetails userInfo);

    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class UserDetails
    {
        int userid;
        string username;
        string password;
        string country;
        string email;



        [DataMember]
        public int UserID
        {
            get { return userid; }
            set { userid = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return username; }
            set { username = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set { password = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Country
        {
            get { return country; }
            set { country = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Service1.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace UserDetails1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public DataSet SelectUserDetails()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa; Password=saviant");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from RegistrationTable", con);

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }

        public string InsertUserDetail(UserDetails userInfo)
        {
            string Message;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa; Password=saviant");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into RegistrationTable(UserName,Password,Country,Email) values(@UserName,@Password,@Country,@Email)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userInfo.UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", userInfo.Password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", userInfo.Country);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userInfo.Email);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                Message = userInfo.UserName + " Details inserted successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                Message = userInfo.UserName + " Details not inserted successfully";
            }
            con.Close();
            return Message;
        }


        public void UpdateRegistrationTable(UserDetails userInfo)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa;Password=saviant");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update RegistrationTable set UserName=@UserName,Password=@Password,Country=@Country, Email=@Email where UserID=@UserID", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userInfo.UserID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userInfo.UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", userInfo.Password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", userInfo.Country);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userInfo.Email);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

        public bool DeleteUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa;Password=saviant");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from RegistrationTable where UserID=@UserID", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userInfo.UserID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return true;
        }

        public DataSet UpdateUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa;Password=saviant");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from RegistrationTable where UserID=@UserID", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userInfo.UserID);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

web.config(Client)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_UserDetails1.Service1" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:50861/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="ServiceReference1.UserDetails1Service1" />
        </client>


    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client call

```
 function CallService() {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                //type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                //url: Url, // Location of the service
                //data: Data, //Data sent to server
                //contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
                //dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
                //processdata: varProcessData, //True or False

                async: true,
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://localhost:50861/Service1.svc/SelectUserDetails",
                dataType: "json",                
                crossDomain: true,
              //  data: '{"teamId":"' + teamId + '", "weekNumber":"' + weekNumber + '"}',
                success: function (content) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(content);
                  //  DisplayRun(map, content);
                },

                error: function (msg) {
                    debugger;
                    ServiceFailed(msg)// When Service call fails
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    debugger;
                    alert("fail" + msg);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Where is the jquery AJAX part ?

Comment: I am stuck since last 3 days. Tried every possible solution. Can somebody please please help me with this?

Comment: @Ramiz: Edited with jquery AJAX part. Please have  a look

Comment: Are you able to browse this URL http://localhost:50861/Service1.svc/SelectUserDetails when in debug mode

Comment: I do not get any data nor do I get any error :(. Its just the blank screen that gets displayed. But yea..When I call this WCF using normal C# code, I am able to perform all operatios. Problem is with jquery. I am making some mistake in configuration fil, but am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Even with just  localhost:50861/Service1.svc ?

Comment: Na localhost:50861/Service1.svc runs perfectly fine

Comment: Have you tried setting jQuery.support.cors to true? From the jQuery site: "cors is equal to true if a browser can create an XMLHttpRequest object and if that XMLHttpRequest object has a withCredentials property. To enable cross-domain requests in environments that do not support cors yet but do allow cross-domain XHR requests (windows gadget, etc), set $.support.cors = true;"

Comment: @Erwin: Just to get clarity , If an XMLHttpRequest is not allowed , would there be a 400 response ?

Comment: No, I get a "no transport" error msg in my ajax call when I don't use cors = true.

Comment: Yes I did try setting $.Support.cors=true. It did not work for me

Comment: So I don't think this related to your ajax call - I think this is a WCF problem. I took just your WCF service built it, ran and turned on tracing. I see this in the trace. "System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty." searching for this error I see various solutions none of which worked for me. I am using VS 2012 update 2. I am at work but I will try and figure this out this weekend. What is your exact environment.

Comment: Hi Kenn:I am using "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web". I may be wrong in asking this question but just want to let you know that If I call same WCF using ASP.NET application it works perfectly fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

My experience: Remove the `<wsHttpBinding>`-node from the web.config. I don't know why but it works.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/f9d490bb-c93d-440a-a9ce-849912d4b172/wcf-auf-iis-80-there-was-no-channel-actively-listening?forum=aspnetajaxmvcde#05b6c5c2-aaca-4060-81f0-75d6561a7aa1
Since a few days on IIS 7.5 too (formerly only on iis 8.0).